# Flow along hyperbolas

Tags: dynamical-systems, conic-sections, integer-lattices

Let’s say there are some hyperbolas:

[image]

and points are told to flow along the hyperbolic curves. I’ve read about horocyclic flow on the space of unit lattices.

I think it would make sense to use matrices to apply a linear transformation acting on the space of unit lattices to achieve a flow of constant speed.

> Q: Is it possible to use matrices to describe the dynamics of points that flow at different speeds along the curves? Are matrices equipped to deal with such flows?

Context:

[The Space of Lattices](http://www.stevejtrettel.com/the-space-of-lattices.html)

[Lorenz and Modular Flows](http://www.josleys.com/articles/ams_article/Lorenz3.htm)

Comment: I suggest that you solve the equation $x''=x$.

Comment: Perhaps adding some context: what you call "modular flow" is simply a very particular case of a geodesic flow, which in the case of constant negative curvature corresponds to the solutions of $x''=x$. So indeed, up to conjugation, it is sufficient to solve this equation.